# Help to evaluate integral in cartesian and cylindrical

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to solve $$\iint_{R} (x+z)dR$$ where R is the first octant of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=9$ and between $z=0$ and $z=4$

I think it could be done in either cylindrical or Cartesian.

I am having trouble finding correct bounds and relating z.

In polar we could have $r^2=9$, and first octant would be $0$ to $\pi/2$ but I don't know how to proceed.

I am also confused because it is a double integral and I thought that cylindrical was used for triple. I really need help. I don't know how to do it
Even if I know the ranges for $\theta$ and z, how does r being 3 come into use? I am so confused

Comment: I share your confusion about the number of iterated integrals. Are you sure the integral isn't over the boundary of the region you describe?

Comment: It is,  "Where R is the first octant portion of the cylinder x^2+y^2=9 between z=0 and z=4"

Comment: Oh, yes, so notice that $x^2+y^2 = 9$ defined a cylinder, not a prism, i.e. it is just the edge, not filled in. As you are integrating over a 2 dimensional object, you get two integral signs. Whether you choose to evaluate that integral in rectangular coordinates or any other, doesn't change the number of integrals, it just might make it easier or harder to compute.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to compute it

Comment: You want to re-write the information you have in terms of cylindrical coordinates. $x^2 + y^2 = 9$ gives you $r = 3$, "between $z=0$ and $z=4$" gives you $0\leq z\leq 4$, what does the first octant part give you?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the 0 to \pi/2 ?

Comment: Yep, so the bounds on the integral will be $0\leq z \leq 4$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$.

Comment: Okay, but then how does r=3 come into it all?

Comment: In the integrand. You have to express $x + z$ in cylindrical coordinates, which will involve $r$.

Comment: Can you please post as an answer explaining such if you have time , I am still stuck

Comment: I think reading this may help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral , or perhaps just googling "surface integral". You are right that you need to do more than just compute boundary conditions, which is what I initially thought was your problem (sorry, I was slow catching on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so, after our discussion in the comments, I think I see what your problem is.

What you are trying to compute is called a "surface integral". You have a function $f(x,y,z)=x+z$ and a surface, and you want to integrate the function over this surface. An analogous situation you may be more happy with is doing a line integral: where you have a line in space, and a function $f$ that you want to integrate along that line.

In both cases you start by parametrizing the object over which you are integrating. Lets parametrise the portion of the cylinder in the question.

So, you've spotted two changing parameters, the height $z$ and the angle $\theta$. We can easily turn this into a parametrization of the surface, for instance, $G(\theta,z) = (3\cos\theta, 3 \sin\theta, z)$ with $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$, and $z\in[0,4]$ works. call this domain $D$. With this in place we can compute the surface integral as
$$
\int\int_R f(x,y,z) d R = \int\int_D f(G(\theta,z))||\textbf{N}(\theta,z)|| d\theta dz
$$
where
$$\textbf{N}(\theta,z) = \frac{\partial G}{d\theta}\times \frac{\partial G}{d z}$$
Lets compute what these are.
$$\frac{\partial G}{d\theta} = (-3\sin\theta,3\cos\theta,0), \frac{\partial G}{d z} = (0,0,1) $$
So, their cross product is $(3\cos\theta,3\sin\theta,0)$, and this has length $3$. So then
$$
\int_0^4\int_0^{\pi/2} (3\cos\theta + z)\cdot 3 d\theta d z
$$
is the integral you want to compute.

Comment: PS: If I wanted to also do in Cartesian, could I express the projection on xz plane as say y=g(x,z)=\sqrt(9-x^2) , and calculus dS, in which case I would have a Cartesian integral with z going from 0 to 4, but what would the bounds for x be?

Comment: Because I am trying to do both but cant get the same answer, I don't know the right bounds

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what integrals, and what substitution, represents. Remember, an integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ is best understood as the "area under $f$" and $\int \int f(x,y) dxdy$ is the "volume under $f$". The problem with integrating over a curved surface (instead of a flat plane) is that volume gets slightly distorted: You don't just cut the plane up into little squares, and approximate the integral by prisms, because the bases are no longer flat.

This explains the distorting factor $||N(x,y)||$.

So, when you actually compute an integral, you are always in rectangular ...

Comment: ... coordinates, you have just *also* had to change the function you are integrating. For instance, to compute the iterated integral $\int \int \int f(x,y,z) dV$, you can express $f$ in cylindrical coordinates, but then $dV = r drd\theta dz$. This extra $r$ has changed the function being integrated.

So to compute a surface integral, you need some parametrization of the surface, but parametrizations don't come in different kinds of coordinates, it's just a function in terms of some *entierly new* variables that give you the surface. So, i'm not quite sure what you mean.